# What is correct style for displaying dollar figures in a column in a table?

Tags: tables

I have a table of two columns. One is list of expenses (or revenue). The other is dollar figures.

Should the dollar sign ($) appear with *every* figure?  Or should I put it only with the figure on the first line and again with the sum (as I believe I was taught years ago in school)?

See the sample I posted (as a response to another question) before I was advised to start a new thread:  [How to format tables with monetary data?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51126/how-to-format-tables-with-monetary-data#new-answer?newreg=c2c807b2c8eb4db9a1d76c4f52e7ca42)

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format tables with monetary data?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51126/how-to-format-tables-with-monetary-data)

Comment: I voted to close the question because it reads like a review request. Can you explain why the answers in the other post don’t answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Including the dollar would have the following advantages:

- Data is very often copied from one application to another, including the dollar in the cell would be very helpful when copying to an email or excel
- It might help with accessibility, as [screen readers could correctly announce the dollar amounts](https://www.tpgi.com/money-talks-formatting-currency-in-web-content/)
- In large tables it helps provide context, for example if there are two amounts next to each other. It can avoid to look up to the header column.